# Is there a way such that when the overloaded true operator of a class returns true, the compiler knows that its nullable member is not null

Tags: c#, nullable

I wish to be able to do the following without receiving a message from the compiler that bar may be null when dereferencing foo.bar.

```
Foo foo = new Foo();

if (foo)
{
    Console.WriteLine(foo.bar.Name);
}
```

I thought I might be able to do that in the following way:

```
public class Bar
{
    public string Name { get; } = "Bar";
}
public class Foo
{
    public Bar? bar;

    public Foo() => bar = null;

    [MemberNotNullWhen(true, nameof(bar))]
    public static bool operator true(Foo instance)
    {
        return instance.bar != null;
    }
    public static bool operator false(Foo instance)
    {
        return instance.bar == null;
    }
}
```

But it doesn't seem to work and I still get the compiler warning. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I doubt this is supported.

Comment: I even would lean out the window and call that a ... suboptimal solution to whatever problem you are trying to solve (even if it _were_ supported). Such an implementation would be very surprising to anyone that is not deeply familiar with your code base. => I don't want to say "bad" idea ... but maybe you can do better and should then prefer that.

Comment: I agree with @Fildor. Just because operator overloading exists, it doesn't mean it always makes sense to use it. More often than not, overloading operators cause confusion when reading the code using these operators.

Comment: @Sweeper When you say not supported, do you mean that the compiler does not support such detection?

I only ask because the code I put does work and the if statement will never be executed when foo.bar is null as far as I can tell.

Comment: Yes, I mean that the compiler does not support such detection.

Comment: @Fildor That's a very fair comment, it's not intuitive that bar is not null when foo is true. I am trying to model a composition. A slot which contains something. So the state of the slot is tied to the state of its components. It evaluates to true when it is not empty. 

I could just test foo.bar != null but I think the code in my question is more elegant - so long as the public interface is properly documented. Maybe that's a moot point considering the innate confusion such code could cause which is arguably much more important. I'll use a more conventional approach.